# Prototype.js 1.6 new element class and IE >= 9

Tags: prototypejs, internet-explorer-9

Then I'm trying to create a new element with, for example

```
new Element('div',{'class':'name'});
```

all browsers create a new element with class "name". But in Internet Explorer 9 and 10 I've got this

```
<div className="name"></div>
```

As you see it creates className attribute instead of class.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
//This generates 'className':
var popoutControl = new Element('div', {'class':'mySuperCoolClassName'});

// Break the line up into two lines. 
// The following will generate a 'class' attribute instead:
var popoutControl = new Element('div');
popoutControl.className = 'mySuperCoolClassName';
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
new Element('div',{'class':'name'});
```

with

```
var mydiv = new Element('div');
mydiv.addClassName('name');
```

As suggested from http://prototypejs.org/api/element/classNames Element.**ClassName**('name');
is deprecated and you should use Element.**addClassName**().

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20668126/1274995

Basically, Prototype 1.6 is buggy in those versions of IE. You should update Prototype. the problem is the translation list contained in Element._attributeTranslations.write

[image: Object Element._attributeTranslations.write in Prototype 1.6.0.3]

This is the list in Prototype 1.7 (And above, I suppose)

[image: Element._attributeTranslations.write in Prototype 1.7+]

I guess that worked in older versions of IE (That were probably current before IE9).