# Prototype.js return className instead of class in ie9

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to create new element and add class for that element.

```
new Element('div',{'class':'name'});
```

**Example**
Other browsers returns

```
<div class="name"></div>
```

IE9 returns

```
<div className="name"></div>
```

How we can fix this issue in prototype.js

Comment: How do you create the new element and add a class to it?

Comment: I have create a new element below format                            `new Element('div',{'class':'name'});`

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. `className` is the object property that holds the classes applied to an element in the Element object - are you confusing the 2?

Comment: what version of prototype are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
new Element('div',{'class':'name'});
```

with

```
var mydiv = new Element('div');
mydiv.addClassName('name');
```

Comment: these are equal, the Element constructor does this same thing behind the scenes when creating the element

Comment: Did you try it? According to several sources these aren't equal and this solves some IE problems.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are using is buggy in IE9 (Haven't tested other versions of IE, nor other versions of Prototype except the ones below). I advise you to update Prototype. Test this in the console (F12 tools):

```
Version 1.7:
    (new Element('div', {className: 'buggy'})).outerHTML
        returns "<div class="buggy"></div>"

    (new Element('div', {class: 'buggy'})).outerHTML
        returns "<div class="buggy"></div>"

Version 1.6.0.3:
    (new Element('div', {className: 'buggy'})).outerHTML
        returns "<div className="buggy"></div>"

    (new Element('div', {class: 'buggy'})).outerHTML
        returns "<div className="buggy"></div>"
```

(Sorry for the late response, I just had to debug this in IE9)